# Now at IDE 1.0.5, should I upgrade to 1.0.6 or 1.5.7 Beta for Pro mini and ATMega2560 use?

Tags: arduino-ide

Do I need to **re-install many libraries** (or similar 'house keeping' works)? Is the upgrade straight forward?

Apparently, from Arduino web, one need 1.5 BETA series for use with Due. For Pro Mini, UNO and ATMega2560, should one use **1.5 BETA or 1.0.6** (no beta, presumable stable)?

I am running out of code space. Wonder if the upgrade will install a **newer gcc** compiler and smaller code size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old libraries will work with 1.5 Beta, but you will most likely need to copy any of your own libraries over to the new beta installation, depending on if they were installed to the sketchbook location or inserted into the installation before. That should be about all you need to do after installing the beta for it to work.

The Beta supports all the regular boards as well as the Due and Yun. I doubt you will see any change in binary size if you update. I've been using the beta for some time now and it has been quite stable.

Which version you should use is up to you, the differences are relatively minor. I think the beta adds a few convenient features, but there are no changes to the code or functionality like the switch to v1.0 made.

Comment: gcc version 4.3.2, dated as WinAVR Dec 2008, was used inside IDE 1.0.5. From https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html, latest is 4.9.2 dated July 2014. Any idea what is the 'practical' improvement that one can see, after upgrading to 1.0.6 or 1.5Beta, within the Arduino context, especially in code size optimization,  code size reduction and dead code/data elimination.

Comment: 4.3.2 is deployed with and up to 1.5.6r2. Where it was updated to 4.8.1 IDE 1.5.7. Where the core libraries have been updated as to compile and work with the newer 4.8.1. Mostly the newer GCC was much more strict and produced errors, that were warnings of bad coding style.

Comment: if you have your downloaded libraries in your home or user directory e.g. "C:\Users\mflaga\Documents\Arduino\libraries" than the are compatible and work seamlessly. There is a new path format for the libraries as to support multiple platform. But it is optional. And the same goes for sketch's they can be in the same old location. e.g. C:\Users\mflaga\Documents\Arduino. I readily change IDE's. Where I prefer 1.5.6r2. 1.5.7 has a IDE bug on windows that does a full compile every time. 1.5.6r2 does a fast compile.

Comment: @mpflaga where can I download selective older version (like 1.5.6r2) you mentioned? The web only has link to the latest version 1.5.7

Comment: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/OldSoftwareReleases

Comment: @BrettM since 1.5.x uses gcc 4.8.1, final .hex size is a bit smaller. LTO (link time optimization) has been disabled due to a corner case bug: enabling it further reduces size of .hex

Answer (score 3):

I have had trouble with 1.5.7 (Beta), so I would stick with 1.0.6. As for code space, you might want to look into [Atmel Studio (Free)](http://www.atmel.com/tools/atmelstudio.aspx), which uses a Visual Studio shell as the IDE. It blows the Arduino IDE out-of-water. Atmel is the maker of all the AT chips, so the Atmel Studio IDE is a great IDE for writing AVR code. Lots of tutorials online and there is a Arduino plug in called [Visual Micro (Free also)](http://www.visualmicro.com/).

Comment: Is it right that Atmel studio means programming bare chip, without the benefit of library, which is very useful for interfacing to hardware modules without reading hardware data sheet and register level programming?  What Visual Micro actually does, as their web states, "New Arduino users are guided to work within the normal Arduino framework, in a similar manner to the Arduino IDE. Advanced Arduino users have a range of options that allow the simple (but restricting) Arduino rules to be broken." What extra control (like gcc switches) and other convenience can I get from Visual Micro?

Comment: You get the extra control via the Atmel Studio. The Micro Plugin allows you to use the arduino libraies, Serial monitor and upload feature.